# Download webpage google web toolkit

Tags: gwt

The company I work for is switching its front end to a gwt application and I was wondering if it is possible to write a script (whether with bash and wget or cURL, or java or anything) that enables me to download the actual content of the gwt web application. Because right now if I try with a command such as wget I just download a page with some javascript functions, but none of the actual page content (what I am interested in). I am on the QA side so I guess I am wondering if it is possible to perform such a task without having direct access to the developers code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using a tool called selenium. I am able to easily click through the gwt application record my activity within the application for future use, and get the actual html  generated by the application which I can then parse for desired content and act accordingly. The only small drawback is that selenium does require the use of a browser, unlike htmlunit or httpunit.

Answer (score 1):

GWT builds the the page (DOM) in place with javascript. So yo would need something that renders the initial DOM, runs the javascript that alters/produces elements and then output the whole DOM. Basically you need a browser.

Your best option would be to look for a browser extension that saves whole pages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some general background on crawlability in AJAX applications.

http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Here is code for a sample servlet that implements that crawlability spec by feeding a page into HTMLUnit , causing all the HTML to be rendered, then sending the results back to the web crawler.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/branches/crawlability/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/server/CrawlServlet.java?r=6211

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had previously implemented the HTMLUnit code to try and generate the html from the application I am testing, but it does not generate any of the actual body html of the application, it simply returns the head section mentioning javascript and css references. I need to look into this a little more and see if I can tweak the server request or something like that. I believe it is possible to do because using firebug I am able to view the html of the application I just haven't figured it out with HTMLUnit.